# Can not run Blender with optirun. [Manjaro 18.1.5]

Tags: gpu, linux

Good Morning all,

I am not able to run Blender with optirun. However I do have all drivers installed, bumblebee etc.. I am able to run optirun with all the other applications, glxgears, firefox or even Gimp.

Here are some outputs about my config :

```
mhwd -lh -d                                                                                                                   

06: PCI 300.0: ff00 Unclassified device
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:03:00.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Realtek RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader"
  Vendor: pci 0x10ec "Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd."
  Device: pci 0x5249 "RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x01
  Driver: "rtsx_pci"
  Driver Modules: "rtsx_pci"
  Memory Range: 0xdd600000-0xdd600fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 126 (30 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010ECd00005249sv00001462sd0000116BbcFFsc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: rtsx_pci is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe rtsx_pci"
  Attached to: #26 (PCI bridge)

07: PCI 17.0: 0106 SATA controller (AHCI 1.0)
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:17.0
  Hardware Class: storage
  Model: "Intel HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa103 "HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x31
  Driver: "ahci"
  Driver Modules: "ahci"
  Memory Range: 0xdd128000-0xdd129fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xdd12c000-0xdd12c0ff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xf090-0xf097 (rw)
  I/O Ports: 0xf080-0xf083 (rw)
  I/O Ports: 0xf060-0xf07f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0xdd12b000-0xdd12b7ff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 127 (17784 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A103sv00001462sd0000116Bbc01sc06i01"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: ahci is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe ahci"

08: PCI 1f.2: 0580 Memory controller
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.2
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa121 "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x31
  Memory Range: 0xdd124000-0xdd127fff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A121sv00001462sd0000116Bbc05sc80i00"

09: PCI 1c.0: 0604 PCI bridge (Normal decode)
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1c.0
  Hardware Class: bridge
  Model: "Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa110 "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0xf1
  Driver: "pcieport"
  IRQ: 16 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A110sv00001462sd0000116Bbc06sc04i00"

10: PCI 1f.0: 0601 ISA bridge
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.0
  Hardware Class: bridge
  Model: "Intel HM170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa14e "HM170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x31
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A14Esv00001462sd0000116Bbc06sc01i00"

11: PCI 200.0: 0200 Ethernet controller
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:02:00.0
  Hardware Class: network
  Model: "Bigfoot Networks Killer N1525 Wireless-AC"
  Vendor: pci 0x168c "Qualcomm Atheros"
  Device: pci 0x003e "QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1a56 "Bigfoot Networks, Inc."
  SubDevice: pci 0x1525 "Killer N1525 Wireless-AC"
  Revision: 0x20
  Driver: "ath10k_pci"
  Driver Modules: "ath10k_pci"
  Device File: wlp2s0
  Memory Range: 0xdd200000-0xdd3fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 130 (22509 events)
  HW Address: c4:8e:8f:9d:35:07
  Permanent HW Address: c4:8e:8f:9d:35:07
  Link detected: yes
  Module Alias: "pci:v0000168Cd0000003Esv00001A56sd00001525bc02sc80i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: ath10k_pci is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe ath10k_pci"
  Attached to: #9 (PCI bridge)

12: PCI 01.0: 0604 PCI bridge (Normal decode)
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:01.0
  Hardware Class: bridge
  Model: "Intel Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x1901 "Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x07
  Driver: "pcieport"
  IRQ: 16 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00001901sv00001462sd0000116Bbc06sc04i00"

13: PCI 16.0: 0780 Communication controller
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:16.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa13a "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x31
  Driver: "mei_me"
  Driver Modules: "mei_me"
  Memory Range: 0xdd12d000-0xdd12dfff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 128 (39 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A13Asv00001462sd0000116Bbc07sc80i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: mei_me is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe mei_me"

14: PCI 100.0: 0302 3D controller
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "nVidia GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x139b "GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0xff
  Memory Range: 0xdc000000-0xdcffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xb0000000-0xbfffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xc0000000-0xc1ffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xe000-0xe07f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0xdd000000-0xdd07ffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 16 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd0000139Bsv00001462sd0000116Bbc03sc02i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: nouveau is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nouveau"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: nvidia_drm is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidia_drm"
  Driver Info #2:
    Driver Status: nvidia is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidia"
  Attached to: #12 (PCI bridge)

15: PCI 1c.3: 0604 PCI bridge (Normal decode)
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1c.3
  Hardware Class: bridge
  Model: "Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa113 "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0xf1
  Driver: "pcieport"
  IRQ: 19 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A113sv00001462sd0000116Bbc06sc04i00"

16: PCI 1f.3: 0403 Audio device
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa170 "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x31
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xdd120000-0xdd123fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xdd100000-0xdd10ffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 131 (726 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A170sv00001462sd0000116Bbc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"

17: PCI 00.0: 0600 Host bridge
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:00.0
  Hardware Class: bridge
  Model: "Intel Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x1910 "Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x07
  Driver: "skl_uncore"
  Driver Modules: "intel_uncore"
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00001910sv00001462sd0000116Bbc06sc00i00"

18: PCI 3e00.0: 0108 Non-Volatile memory controller (NVM Express)
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:3e:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:3e:00.0
  Hardware Class: storage
  Model: "Toshiba America Info NVMe Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x1179 "Toshiba America Info Systems"
  Device: pci 0x010f "NVMe Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1179 "Toshiba America Info Systems"
  SubDevice: pci 0x0001 
  Revision: 0x01
  Driver: "nvme"
  Driver Modules: "nvme"
  Memory Range: 0xdd400000-0xdd403fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 16 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001179d0000010Fsv00001179sd00000001bc01sc08i02"
  Attached to: #19 (PCI bridge)

19: PCI 1d.0: 0604 PCI bridge (Normal decode)
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1d.0
  Hardware Class: bridge
  Model: "Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa118 "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0xf1
  Driver: "pcieport"
  IRQ: 16 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A118sv00001462sd0000116Bbc06sc04i00"

20: PCI 14.2: 1180 Signal processing controller
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:14.2
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa131 "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x31
  Driver: "intel_pch_thermal"
  Driver Modules: "intel_pch_thermal"
  Memory Range: 0xdd12e000-0xdd12efff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 18 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A131sv00001462sd0000116Bbc11sc80i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: intel_pch_thermal is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe intel_pch_thermal"

21: PCI 1c.4: 0604 PCI bridge (Normal decode)
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1c.4
  Hardware Class: bridge
  Model: "Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa114 "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0xf1
  Driver: "pcieport"
  IRQ: 16 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A114sv00001462sd0000116Bbc06sc04i00"

22: PCI 400.0: 0200 Ethernet controller
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:04:00.0
  Hardware Class: network
  Model: "Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x1969 "Qualcomm Atheros"
  Device: pci 0xe0a1 "Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x10
  Driver: "alx"
  Driver Modules: "alx"
  Device File: enp4s0
  Memory Range: 0xdd500000-0xdd53ffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xd000-0xd07f (rw)
  IRQ: 19 (no events)
  HW Address: d8:cb:8a:ef:70:75
  Permanent HW Address: d8:cb:8a:ef:70:75
  Link detected: no
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001969d0000E0A1sv00001462sd0000116Bbc02sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: alx is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe alx"
  Attached to: #15 (PCI bridge)

23: PCI 02.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:02.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Device Name: "Onboard IGD"
  Model: "Intel HD Graphics 530"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x191b "HD Graphics 530"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x06
  Driver: "i915"
  Driver Modules: "i915"
  Memory Range: 0xdb000000-0xdbffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x70000000-0x7fffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xf000-0xf03f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0x000c0000-0x000dffff (rw,non-prefetchable,disabled)
  IRQ: 129 (88507 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000191Bsv00001462sd0000116Bbc03sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: i915 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe i915"

24: PCI 14.0: 0c03 USB Controller (XHCI)
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:14.0
  Hardware Class: usb controller
  Model: "Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa12f "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x31
  Driver: "xhci_hcd"
  Driver Modules: "xhci_pci"
  Memory Range: 0xdd110000-0xdd11ffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 125 (155 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A12Fsv00001462sd0000116Bbc0Csc03i30"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: xhci_pci is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe xhci_pci"

25: PCI 1f.4: 0c05 SMBus
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.4
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.4
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa123 "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0x31
  Driver: "i801_smbus"
  Driver Modules: "i2c_i801"
  Memory Range: 0xdd12a000-0xdd12a0ff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0xf040-0xf05f (rw)
  IRQ: 16 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A123sv00001462sd0000116Bbc0Csc05i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: i2c_i801 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe i2c_i801"

26: PCI 1c.2: 0604 PCI bridge (Normal decode)
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1c.2
  Hardware Class: bridge
  Model: "Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa112 "100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0x116b 
  Revision: 0xf1
  Driver: "pcieport"
  IRQ: 18 (no events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A112sv00001462sd0000116Bbc06sc04i00"
03: USB 00.0: 11500 Bluetooth Device
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-10:1.0
  Hardware Class: bluetooth
  Model: "Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x0cf3 "Qualcomm Atheros Communications"
  Device: usb 0x3004 "AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0"
  Revision: "0.01"
  Driver: "btusb"
  Driver Modules: "btusb"
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v0CF3p3004d0001dcE0dsc01dp01icE0isc01ip01in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: ath3k is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe ath3k"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: btusb is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe btusb"
  Attached to: #6 (Hub)

04: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-7:1.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "MSI EPF USB"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1770 "MSI EPF USB"
  Device: usb 0xff00 "MSI EPF USB"
  Revision: "1.10"
  Serial ID: "MSI EPF USB"
  Driver: "usbhid"
  Driver Modules: "usbhid"
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v1770pFF00d0110dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc00ip00in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: usbhid is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe usbhid"
  Attached to: #6 (Hub)

06: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-0:1.0
  Hardware Class: hub
  Model: "Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1d6b "Linux Foundation"
  Device: usb 0x0002 "2.0 root hub"
  Revision: "4.19"
  Serial ID: "0000:00:14.0"
  Driver: "hub"
  Driver Modules: "usbcore"
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v1D6Bp0002d0419dc09dsc00dp01ic09isc00ip00in00"

07: USB 00.0: 10a00 Hub
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-0:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 2-0:1.0
  Hardware Class: hub
  Model: "Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x1d6b "Linux Foundation"
  Device: usb 0x0003 "3.0 root hub"
  Revision: "4.19"
  Serial ID: "0000:00:14.0"
  Driver: "hub"
  Driver Modules: "usbcore"
  Module Alias: "usb:v1D6Bp0003d0419dc09dsc00dp03ic09isc00ip00in00"
```

An other output:

```
mhwd -li -d                                                                                                                   

   NAME:    video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.10.25
   INFO:    Hybrid bumblebee solution for NVIDIA Optimus Technology - Closed source NVIDIA driver & open source intel driver.
   PRIORITY:    12
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-440xx video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 0300 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 8086
```

And here is the output when I run Blender with optirun :

```
~/blender-2.81a-linux-glibc217-x86_64 >>> sudo optirun ./blender                                                                    
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
```

That's it, nothing more ! And here is the crash.txt :

```
cat /tmp/blender.crash.txt                                                           [139]
# Blender 2.81 (sub 16), Commit date: 2019-12-04 11:32, Hash f1aa4d18d49d

# backtrace
./blender(BLI_system_backtrace+0x1d) [0x14ee84d]
./blender() [0x12cbb79]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x3bfb0) [0x7f21fdaf1fb0]
./blender(_ZN16GHOST_ContextGLX24initializeDrawingContextEv+0x2d4) [0x322d6e4]
./blender(_ZN15GHOST_WindowX1117newDrawingContextE25GHOST_TDrawingContextType+0x8b) [0x322cb5b]
./blender(_ZN12GHOST_Window21setDrawingContextTypeE25GHOST_TDrawingContextType+0x7e) [0x322f52e]
./blender(_ZN15GHOST_WindowX11C1EP15GHOST_SystemX11P9_XDisplayRK10STR_Stringiijj18GHOST_TWindowStatePS_25GHOST_TDrawingContextTypebbbbb+0x5f1) [0x322c201]
./blender(_ZN15GHOST_SystemX1112createWindowERK10STR_Stringiijj18GHOST_TWindowState25GHOST_TDrawingContextType16GHOST_GLSettingsbbPK13GHOST_IWindow+0xa6) [0x3229996]
./blender(GHOST_CreateWindow+0x61) [0x3224351]
./blender() [0x16c83cd]
./blender(wm_window_ghostwindows_ensure+0x2d) [0x16c84ed]
./blender(WM_check+0x4a) [0x169d91a]
./blender(wm_homefile_read+0x316) [0x16acbb6]
./blender(WM_init+0x138) [0x16b2798]
./blender(main+0x280) [0x1237f00]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f21fdadd153]
./blender() [0x12c849c]
```

I hope that I provided enough information, please feel free to ask me the output of other commands !

Cordially,
Joni.

Ohh, and Happy New Year ! :)

Comment: What is optirun? Is this a custom Blender Build or a question about compiling Blender?

Comment: optirun is the command that enable you to run application with the discrete graphic card, it's for computers having hybrid gpu, in my case intel/nvidia. it comes with bumblebee. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee